# displaying image reusable content with pieces

Tags: image, apostrophe-cms

I wrote a Widget – i basically created the *people* Widget ( *Adding Editable Content to Pages* - Tutorial) and modified it to my needs.

[The structure of the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AlvO.png)

On my show.html the heroimage is missing and everywhere else the image is displayed properly.

Does anyone have a clou, what i am missing?

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AlvO.png)
[project index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS99I.png)

[show.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiKZj.png)

Answer (score 1):

The code screenshots give an incomplete picture but a few things to double check or try:

Is `heroimage` actually a part of your project's schema?

In `show.html` are you tucking `data.piece` into its own variable? I would think the line would be 

`{% set image = apos.images.first(data.piece.heroimage) %}`